# JsonObjectRequest with Username and Password

Tags: java, android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I get JSON with user and password in Xamarin and all works, but now I tried to learn Android SDK and I want to get JSON with JsonObjectRequest.

In Xamarin it works with this code so I am looking for the same thing in Android

```
   var response = await new HttpClient(
     new HttpClientHandler(){
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password),
            }).GetStringAsync(url);
  var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NodeInfo[]>(response);
    }
```

In Android I tried it and get JSON.

```
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

But now i need to get JSON with permission like in Xamarin can anyone give me advice please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `getHeaders()` function of the `JsonObjectRequest`:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, JSONObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        //handle response here
    }}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //handle error here
    }}) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
               Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();                
               String credentials = "username:password";
               String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
               headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
               headers.put("Authorization", auth);
               return headers;
        }
}
```

Comment: You can either just overwrite the `getHeaders()` method of your request locally (see edited answer) or you can create your own custom request, if you plan to use it more often. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) for this.